# checking a checkbox has no effect in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

Inside a frame, I have populated checkboxes. But checking them has no effect on the checkbox_vars. what could be wrong with this piece of code?

```
def set_insider_trades():

    def on_mousewheel(event):
        canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")

    set_inside_trading = tk.Tk()
    set_inside_trading.title("Set Insider Trading")
    set_inside_trading.geometry("300x600")

    # Add a Scrollbar to the Canvas
    scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(set_inside_trading, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
    scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

    # Create a Canvas
    canvas = tk.Canvas(set_inside_trading, borderwidth=0, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    # Configure the scrollbar to scroll the canvas
    scrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

    # Create a Frame within the Canvas
    frame = tk.Frame(canvas)

    # Add the Frame to the Canvas
    canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame, anchor=tk.NW)

    # Configure the Canvas Scroll Region
    frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

    # Bind Mousewheel Event to Scroll
    frame.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", on_mousewheel)

    # Create checkboxes for each company
    checkbox_vars = {company: tk.BooleanVar(value=False) for company in df.index}
    for idx, (company, var) in enumerate(checkbox_vars.items()):
        checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(frame, text=company, variable=var)
        checkbox.grid(row=idx, column=0, sticky="w", padx=(10, 0), pady=5)

    def update_companies():
        for company, var in checkbox_vars.items():
            if var.get():
                df.loc[company, 'Insider & SAST Buys Last Quarter'] = 1
            else:
                df.loc[company, 'Insider & SAST Buys Last Quarter'] = 0


    ok_button = tk.Button(set_inside_trading, text="OK", command=lambda: [update_companies(), set_inside_trading.destroy()])
    ok_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=1.0, anchor=tk.S)
```

Comment: there is an unresolved reference `df` in the code. Could you please edit the question? 
[minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Why do lambdas defined in a loop with different values all return the same result? https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result.

Answer (score 1):

tried some debugging using callback function. I found that the checkbox state is not being updated as expected. This usually happens when a new Tkinter instance (Tk() or Toplevel()) is created while another one is still running, causing unexpected behavior due to conflicts between the two instances.

**set_insider_trades() creates a new Tk() window. I changed it to Toplevel() and it worked fine.**

In Tkinter, there should only be one Tk() instance, which serves as the main application window. Any additional windows should be instances of Toplevel(). This was the root of the problem.